# AngularJS Code Documentation Tool

Tags: gratis, open-source, javascript, angularjs, documentation-generator

Is there any Free open source Code Documentation Tool for AngularJS projects.

I've used YUIDoc JavaScript Code Documentation Tool but it does not seem to be very suitable for AngularJS, because the final documentation that gets generated does not speak in AngularJS terms instead it speaks JavaScript terms like "Objects", "Methods", "properties", etc. Whereas, AngularJS terms such as "Modules", "Controllers", "Directives", "Services", etc are not openly available so its not easy for the readers to understand.

OS: Windows, but ideally OS agnostic

I'm trying out [ngDoc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation) it seems to be better for AngularJS.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Important details include e.g.: what features do you need? What kind of documentation (JavaDoc like? Others?)

Comment: Can you tell us which o/s the tool should run on (add a tag)? Must it be free (use the [tag:gratis] tag, or do you have a budget? What features are "must have" and "nice to have"? What is wrong with YUIDoc and what else have you tried? The more information that you provide us, the easier it will be for us to help you (disclaimer: I am very interested in the answer to this question ;-)

Comment: I've updated the question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying out [ngDoc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation) it seems to be better for AngularJS. 
But I'm keeping this open for further comments and suggestions.

Comment: And I am following it ;-)  Please do come back after awhile and post what you decided on. Thanks